# How to display 5 inputs in 1 row on a page with a custom width in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I want to have 5 inputs in 1 row on a page with a custom width, for example: the amount input should be smaller and the offer input should be bigger I am trying but I do not understand how to do this. I tried adding 5 columns and then added col-lg-2 class to the inputs I want small and col-lg-4 to the ones I want bigger, it looks good but the submit button is not shown in the same row. any ideas? how to do this?

Here's the code I use

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="search-form-amount form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="search-form-currency form-control"> 
                <option value="AED">AED</option>
                <option value="AFN">AFN</option>
                <option value="ALL">ALL</option>
                <option value="AMD">AMD</option>
                <option value="ANG">ANG</option>
                <option value="AOA">AOA</option>
                <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
                <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
                <option value="AWG">AWG</option>
                <option value="AZN">AZN</option>
                <option value="BAM">BAM</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="search-form-currency form-control"> 
                <option value="BQ">Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba</option>
                <option value="AL">Albania</option>
                <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
                <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
                <option value="AO">Angola</option>
                <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
                <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
                <option value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="search-form-currency form-control"> 
                <optgroup label="All payment methods">
                  <option value="ALL_ONLINE">All online offers</option>
                  <option value="NATIONAL_BANK">National bank transfer</option>
                  <option value="SEPA">SEPA (EU) bank transfer</option>
                  <option value="SPECIFIC_BANK">Transfers with specific bank</option>
                  <option value="INTERNATIONAL_WIRE_SWIFT">International Wire (SWIFT)</option>
                  <option value="OTHER">Other online payment</option>
                  <option value="CASH_DEPOSIT">Cash deposit</option>
                  <option value="ECOCASH">EcoCash</option>
                </optgroup>  
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" name="find-offers" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
          </div>                                                            
      </div>
  </div>
```

The Result I'm getting:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You have bootstrap 3 and 4 referenced in your tags on this post. Which version are you using? It actually is relevant to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do 3 things to improve the spacing/sizing...

1. Remove gutter from the row using `no-gutters`
2. Add `flex-lg-nowrap` to the row to prevent wrapping on `lg` (and wider)
3. Use the auto-layout grid sizing on the right-most 2 columns

[Codeply demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/FW9rULYo6F)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters flex-lg-nowrap">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="search-form-amount form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 pl-lg-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="search-form-currency form-control">
                    ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pl-lg-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="search-form-currency form-control">
                    ...
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg pl-lg-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="search-form-currency form-control">
                    ..
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-auto pl-lg-1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" name="find-offers" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has 12 cols in a row. What you have now is `col-lg-2 2 4 4 2`, which adds up to 14. So if you want to make all of them into one row, you have to adjust your total col size below 12.

In term of responsive design, you might also want to create `col-` , even `col-sm`, `col-md` so it would layout nicely in smaller screen size.

Comment: You say below 12. lets say I change the col-lg-4 to 2 it'll fix the problem but the size of input will be smaller and that's not what I want.

Comment: @UmerLachi without introducing too many tricks that may cause buggy behaviors for this simple layout. One thing you can do is to add `no-gutters` to reduce gap between `col`. Then proportional your col to make it close to your desired layout. Based on your picture, you might want to try out `3:1:3:4:1` for `lg` screen. Remember `col` will adjust it's width according to your window size. Sometimes you just cannot expect the layout be perfect for all widths. For instance, each col has it's own content (text,button, etc), the minimum button size might be larger than the col under circumstances.